# docusign api not uploading docx or doc files

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using a demo account.
I am connecting through Rest API using `PHP` to sign documents.

When I am uploading a `pdf` document it is working fine but when I upload any other type of document it is giving error. Can anyone confirm if the error is due to demo account.

Error I am receiving is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DocuSign\eSign\ApiException' with message 
[400] Error connecting to the API
```

I have used the codes displayed in the developer pages.

My code:

```
// configure the document we want signed 
$documentFileName = "/test/Docs/test.docx"; 

// working for test.pdf 
$documentName = "test.pdf"; 
// instantiate a new envelopeApi object 
$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient); 
// Add a document to the envelope 
$document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document(); 
$document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents‌​(DIR . $documentFileName))); 
$document->setName($documentName);
```

Comment: My code:  
    // configure the document we want signed  
    $documentFileName = "/test/Docs/test.docx";  //working for test.pdf  
    $documentName = "test.pdf";  
    // instantiate a new envelopeApi object  
    $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);  
    // Add a document to the envelope  
    $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();  
    $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . $documentFileName)));  
    $document->setName($documentName);

Comment: Note: you can edit your own question to add additional information like code samples

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Remember to check (accpt) the best answer to your own questions. And upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For file types other than pdf, you need to explicitly set the file type. This is done with the `fileExtension` field

Try adding

```
$document->setFileExtension("docx"); // Word docx file
```

See [docs for the list of supported file types](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-supported-file-formats).